# Calculate time difference between all dates in column python

Tags: python, performance, dataframe, time, diff

I have a data frame that looks like that:

```
group        date            value
 g_1  1/2/2019 11:03:00        3
 g_1  1/2/2019 11:04:00        5
 g_1  1/2/2019 10:03:32        100
 g_2  4/3/2019 09:11:09        46
```

I want to calculate the time difference between occurrences (in seconds) per group.

Example output:

```
groups_time_diff = {'g_1': [23,5666,7878], 'g_2: [0.2,56,2343] ,...}
```

This is my code:

```
groups_time_diff = defaultdict(list)
for group in tqdm(groups):
    group_df = unit_df[unit_df['group'] == group]    
    dates = list(group_df['time'])
    while len(dates) != 0:
        min_date = min(dates)
        dates.remove(min_date)
        if len(dates) > 0:
            second_min_date = min(dates)
            date_diff = second_min_date - min_date
            groups_time_diff[group].append(date_diff.seconds)
```

This takes forever to run and I am looking for a more time efficient way to get the desired output. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sorted_group_df = group_df.sort_values(by='time',ascending=True)
dates = sorted_group_df['time']
one = dates[1:-1].reset_index(drop=True)
two = dates[0:-1].reset_index(drop=True)
date_difference = one - two
date_difference_in_seconds = date_difference.dt.seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Try at first sort your dates. Then subtract these two series:

```
dates = dates.sort_values()
pd.Series.subtract(dates[0:-1], dates[1:-1])
```

You are using min function twice in each iteration that is not efficient. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that but unfortunately, I get 0 days 00:00:00 for the whole group. whats is the problem?